# Formal power series over a henselian ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a henselian ring. Is $R[[x]]$ also a henselian ring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is. 
More generally, the following result holds.

> **Proposition.** If $R$ is henselian at the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, then $R[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]]$ is henselian at the maximal ideal lying over $\mathfrak{m}$.

A reference is the paper by N. Sankharan [*A Theorem on Henselian Rings*](http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CMB-1968-032-4), Canad. Math. Bull. **11** (1968), 275-277. See in particular Corollary 2.

**Remark.** The Proposition above is no longer valid if one takes the polynomial ring instead of the power series ring. For instance, if $K$ is a field than $K$ is henselian but $K[x]$ is not.

Comment: More generally: if $A$ is a local ring and $I$ an ideal such that $A$ is $I$-adically complete and separated, then $A$ is henselian if (and only if!) $A/I$ is henselian. This is easy by observing that each `$A_n:=A/I^n$` is henselian (because $A_{n,\mathrm{red}}$ is) and then inductively lifting roots to $A$. See Raynaud, LNM 169, I, §2 where this result is given as an exercise.